# LinkLabel text drawn over image

Tags: .net, image, text, label

I have a LinkLabel that I'm assigning an Image to and aligning the image MiddleLeft. The problem is that the label text (also MiddleLeft aligned) is painted over the top of the image rather than to the right (or left for that matter). Is there some way to draw the text to the right of the image while keeping the text left aligned?

TIA

Answer (score 3):

I realise that this question is relatively ancient, and you've probably long since moved on to more important things by now, but I just hit the same problem and I thought I'd update with my solution.

I needed a little icon (16x16) with a link label to the right of it - like a bullet point. I created a LinkLabel, set the Image property, set the Text property and set 18px of left padding to the label - that pushes the text over by 18px, and leaves the image where it is, meaning that AutoSize continues to work as it should and the text is neatly displayed next to the image.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `LinkLabel` has been derived from `Label` without taking care of the image rectangle in the link layout routines.

The `LinkLabel` completely ignores the space the image consumes.

My workaround is to place the `Linklabel` on a Panel, with `LinkLabel.Dock=Fill`, and an `Image` (or `Label` with image and no text) left of it with `Label.Dock=Left`. Looks and works as intended, but you have to use one `Label`/`Image`-`Linklabel`-combination per link.